# How to decode XML entities?

Tags: xml, encoding, erlang

To encode a string to XML, the `xmerl_lib:export_text` function does the job, but which function does the opposite job, i.e. converts `&lt;` to `>`?

I want to convert a complete string like:

```
&lt;foo=&quot;bar&quot;>
```

To:

```
<foo="bar">
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I never was able to find a good library for this, so I've created my own decode function.

```
decode("&gt;" ++ Rest) ->
 ">" ++ decode(Rest);
decode("&lt;" ++ Rest) ->
 "<" ++ decode(Rest);
decode("&quot;" ++ Rest) ->
 "\"" ++ decode(Rest);
decode([]) ->
 [].
```

According to [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Character_encodings_in_HTML#XML_character_references), there are only five character references for XML, so you should be ok with supporting these five:

```
&amp; → & (ampersand, U+0026)
&lt; → < (less-than sign, U+003C)
&gt; → > (greater-than sign, U+003E)
&quot; → " (quotation mark, U+0022)
&apos; → ' (apostrophe, U+0027)
```

Comment: There are also decimal and hexadecimal character references, e.g. `&#65;` and `&#x41;`.

Answer (score 2):

The `exml` package has support for this:

https://github.com/paulgray/exml/blob/master/src/exml.erl#L54

In general, consider exml over xmerl, but be aware it is a NIF-based parser.